# Doctrine2: SUM on left join query

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm trying to build a query with **Doctrine**, but i'm not sure if it can be done.

What i need is to get a result displaying the ID of a Requested Item and its SUM of Quantity already fulfilled.

I have four tables:

- Request
- RequestItems
- Order
- OrderItems

I can create a **Request** and assign one or more Items to this Request which are stored at **RequestItems**, then i need to create an **Order** to this **Request**, the **Order** must aim to fulfill the Requested Items, but it might be with a single Order or Multiple ones, therefore each **Order** contains one or many items which are stored at **OrderItems**.

The following is an example of tables:

```
Request
| ID | Date       |
|----|------------|
|  1 | 2014-05-12 |
|  2 | 2014-05-13 |

RequestItems
| ID | RequestID | Name             |Qtty |
|----|-----------|---------------------|-----|
|  1 |         1 | 60W Light Bulb      |   5 |
|  2 |         1 | Bticino switch      |   3 |
|  3 |         2 | 60W Light Bulb      |  10 |
|  4 |         2 | 80W Light Bulb Warm |  15 |

Order
| ID | RequestId | Date       | State |
|----|-----------|------------|-------|
|  1 |         1 | 2014-05-14 |     1 |
|  2 |         1 | 2014-05-15 |     1 |
|  3 |         2 | 2014-05-15 |     1 |
|  4 |         2 | 2014-05-16 |     1 |
|  5 |         2 | 2014-05-17 |     1 |

OrderItems
| ID | RequestItemsID | OrderID | Qtty |
|----|----------------|---------|------|
|  1 |              1 |       1 |    5 |
|  2 |              2 |       2 |    3 |
|  3 |              3 |       3 |    2 |
|  4 |              3 |       4 |    2 |
|  5 |              3 |       5 |    1 |
|  6 |              4 |       5 |   10 |
```

Here i have two Requests:
No. 1: Have two items requested (5 60W light bulbs, 3 Bticino switches)
No. 2: Have one item requested (10 60W light bulbs, 15 80W warm light bulbs)

For these requests i have created 5 Orders, two of them to fulfill first request and 3 to fulfill second request.

The first two Orders have addressed the first request and provided the requested items so first request should be completed.

The last three Orders are addressing the second Request and have provided already 5 of the 10 60W light bulbs and 10 of the 80W warm light bulbs.

What i need here is to get the ID and Quantity of the RequestItems and The SUM of Qtty on OrderItems grouped by the RequestItem ID and filtered by the Order State and Request ID

As a sample i need to get how many RequestedItems where requested and have already been ordered for the Request No. 2 where its Order State is 1

```
| RequestItemsID | QttyRequested | QttyOrdered (SUM) |
|----------------|---------------|-------------------|
|              3 |            10 |                 5 |
|              4 |            15 |                10 |
```

This result groups requested items by its ID and return the Requested Quantity, also SUM the already ordered ammounts of **OrderItems** for this **RequestItem**

Given this result i can calculate pending items also.

I've managed to solve this issue building two Queries one to get RequestedItems and one to get OrderedItems and matching these two with PHP but i think it is possible to do this on the database side.

If anyone can help me with this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE #1:**

I have issues with subqueries inside a join when using the QueryBuilder, but i managed to build a working query, adding the subquery in the join condition.

I'm adding my working query below but i still need to do multiple checks to see if it is really my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Doctrine doesnt support subqueries in the JOIN part of the query but i managed to add a subquery in the condition part of my JOIN.

Based on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/0rNbXlD0E_8 this can be solved with IN(**SUBQUERY**)

This is what is working right now given the example in the OP

```
SELECT ri.ID AS RequestItemsID, ri.Qtty AS QttyRequested, COALESCE(SUM(oi.Qtty), 0) AS QttyOrdered 
FROM RequestItems AS ri
LEFT JOIN OrderItems AS oi ON oi.RequestItemsID = ri.ID AND oi.OrderID IN (
    SELECT o.ID FROM Order AS o WHERE o.State = 1 AND o.RequestID = 2
)
WHERE ri.RequestID = 2
GROUP BY ri.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the example result by executing

```
SELECT ri.ID AS RequestItemsID, ri.Qtty AS QttyRequested, 
       SUM(oi.qtty) AS QttyOrdered
FROM RequestItems ri 
INNER JOIN Order AS o ON o.RequestId = ri.RequestId
INNER JOIN OrderItems AS oi ON oi.OrderId = o.ID
WHERE ri.RequestId = 2 AND o.State = 1
GROUP BY ri.RequestId, o.State
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your query but it didnt work, first i needed to change the GroupBy as i need to group by the RequestItem ID and not the RequestID, after that i found two problems, the SUM was performed on every row, so if i have more than one RequestItem, each have the same SUM result, and second in case no OrderItems have been added i'm not getting the RequestItem in the result set.
I'm updating the OP to be more specific